# Pricing of agents and parallel jobs in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, when we have more numbers of agents registered than the number of parallel jobs running and the agents are sitting idle for months, does all those agents sitting idle will incur charges?

Just to be clear, my question is more towards the billing that what constitutes the cost. for ex, if we have 20 agents spun up and only 10 of them is sitting idle, will it cost for 10 agents or for all 20 agents? or the number agents does not matter at all and it is only the parallel jobs, and they are not related to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Self-hosted Parallel Jobs are 14.83€ per month, as per [Pricing for Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/) (see bottom left corner of the linked page).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They will not incur charges on your subscription until you configure billing settings. In order to change the billing settings and add additional parallel jobs you should go under parallel jobs and press purchase parallel jobs.

[image]

This will navigate to a new window which is called billing and will connect with your Azure subscription.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my question is more of towards the billing that what constitutes the cost.
for ex, if we have 20 agents spun up and 10 of them is sitting idle, will it cost for 10 agents or for all 20 agents? or the number agents does not matter at all.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it more understandable.